# AJAX in WordPress Template Not Working in WordPress Plugin Class

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, class, plugins

I was wondering if there are different things you need to do for AJAX calls in a plugin class then in a template.

The following code works just fine sitting inside a theme template. However, I am moving this into a plugin. This code is currently inside of a class and I am getting 400 error and am not sure why. It seems weird it works in one place and not another. I must be missing something with WordPress plugin classes verses themes.

Any help or suggestions would be great! Thanks.
'''

```
    function echoPowerAJAX_javascript() {
        $adminAJAX =  admin_url('admin-ajax.php');  
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
        jQuery(function($) {
            $( "select[id=slctAddPowers]" )  
                .change(function( event ) {
                    var s = $(this).val();
                    var disc = $(this).prev().val();
                    var prevDiv = $(this).next('#PowerPreviewContainer');
                    if (s == '') {
                        //hide preview
                        $(prevDiv).html('<div class="alert alert-info">Select a Power from the drop down to display details here.</div>').fadeTo('fast');
                    } else {
                        $(prevDiv).html('<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x"></i>').fadeTo('fast');

                        //dPowerPreviewContainer.innerHTML = '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-2x"></i>';
                        var ajaxurl = <?php echo json_encode($adminAJAX); ?>;
                        console.log('ajaxurl = ' + ajaxurl);                
                        var data = {
                                    action: 'echoPowerAJAX',
                                    powerID: s,
                                    pDetail: 3                          
                                   };
                        console.log("data = ");
                        console.log(data);              
        //            //WP ajax call
                        var tmessage = 'Adding some text here and whatever....';

                        $.post(ajaxurl, data)
                          .done(function( data, success ) {
                            //alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
                            var pwrHTML = $.parseJSON(data);
                            $(prevDiv).html(pwrHTML).fadeTo('fast');
                          });
                    }
          });
      });
    });
    </script>
```

```
    echoPowerAJAX_javascript();
    ?>
```

'''

This is all sitting inside of an ob_start() section now. Still doesn't work if I move the function outside of the ob_start.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the actual AJAX PHP for the request into the plugin. Once that was in I was getting a 200 response but there was still an error. I needed to change the functions in the AJAX PHP to reference the class of the new function and then it started working.